# Why am I receiving TypeError: cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hey so I've been trying to make a Discord bot, in the spirit of Christmas it will have a command, ".suggestgift" which will start a prompt that figures out a good match for the person. I keep receiving the error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined... I don't know why though, the other commands, written the same way all seem to work. Here's my code...

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const WOKCommands = require ('wokcommands');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '.';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.commands.giftsuggest = new Discord.Collection()


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Santa bot is online');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'clear'){
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if(command === 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if(command === 'ban'){
        client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }else if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }else if(command == 'giftprompt'){
        client.commands.giftsuggest.get('giftprompt').execute(message, args);
    }

    
});



client.login('my token would be here')
```

The files code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggestprompt',
    description: 'testing',
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('This is testing to see that the command works')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` returns an object, which is a key value pair, you are missing the key part for execute function

try changing the `module.exports` to below

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggestprompt',
    description: 'testing',
    execute: function(message, args){
        message.channel.send('This is testing to see that the command works')
    }
}
```

**And Welcome to StackOverflow :)**